# Spring Boot jar not works

Tags: spring-boot, maven, jar

I created simple telegram bot on Spring Boot and I am trying to deploy it to the server. So, to do this I need to create executable jar file. I built jar using `mvn clean package`, but it does not work. I can't run this jar from anywhere, except project root folder. When I run it from root folder everything works fine, otherwise I get an exception. I suspect that this strange behaviour is due to errors in dependencies. I've tried a lot of things, like change spring boot maven plugin's target, change jar to war, but nothing works. Is there any ideas how I can fix it and build jar correctly? Thanks for any help.

Project pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>rf3dBot</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>rf3dBot</name>
    <description>rf3dBot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.telegram</groupId>
            <artifactId>telegrambots-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.4</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

build logs:

```
$ mvn clean package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------< com.example:rf3dBot >-------------------------
[INFO] Building rf3dBot 1.0
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[WARNING] The artifact org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.36 has been relocated to org.slf4j:slf4j-reload4j:jar:1.7.36
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.1.0:clean (default-clean) @ rf3dBot ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\Sergey\Desktop\rf3dBot\target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources (default-resources) @ rf3dBot ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 755 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ rf3dBot ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 10 source files to C:\Users\Sergey\Desktop\rf3dBot\target\classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ rf3dBot ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\Sergey\Desktop\rf3dBot\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ rf3dBot ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) @ rf3dBot ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:3.2.2:jar (default-jar) @ rf3dBot ---
[INFO] Building jar: C:\Users\Sergey\Desktop\rf3dBot\target\rf3dBot-1.0.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.6.4:repackage (repackage) @ rf3dBot ---
[INFO] Replacing main artifact with repackaged archive
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  28.204 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-03-26T00:22:44+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

exception (it's not so important, because in the intellij idea application works completely fine)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

try

1. starting your app with a specified profile.
2. error in image shows it gives null pointer exception in RandomMemeBuilder.

U should look this class and check what is causing null pointer execption. or post more code for this class.